# Why does the color for the maximum weight value disappear in multi paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

My color settings for Weight paint.
[image]'

Default mode.

[image]

Multi-Paint mode.

[image]

How can I make multi-paint use the full color scale of the weights?

Comment: i just tested it  - works for me. So pls provide blend file. But you know that max colors are blue and red, not yellow, right?

Comment: @Chris I'm using my custom color range for weight paint display where yellow denote max value.

Comment: would be good if you write these informations in the question so we don't have to make "dumb" comments and don't have to ask....

Comment: @Chris Sorry. I added this information to the post..

Comment: thank you......!

Comment: what weight do the the 2 vertices on the right have? Could you please check in Edit mode in the N panel?